# Variance of the sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance, variance, expected-value

Don't really understand one of the questions on my passed test. :

Suppose X and Y are random variables such that E(XY) = 0. Suppose also each of X and Y has mean 1 and variance 3. Find the variance of X + Y.

I know the answer is 4, but why?

Answer (score 2):

Because
$$\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y) + 2 \operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$$
and also
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}[XY] - \mathbb{E}[X]  \mathbb{E}[Y]$$
and since $ \mathbb{E}[XY] = 0$ then $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) =  -1$. Then simply subsitute the values into the first equation, yielding
\begin{align}\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)&=\operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y) + 2\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)\\
&= 3 \ + 3 \ +2(-1)\\
&= 4.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Compute $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=-1$ and hence $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{Var}X+\operatorname{Var}Y+2\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ gives the value 4.